# Job Application Question - Have you been previously employed us

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, employees

I'm not sure how to answer this question when applying for a position at company A.

Background:

As I was working for a call centre outsourcing company B under the above company A. I was based in company A's premises. Everyone else in my team and team leader was employed under Company B. Is this considered a contracting role?

Company B was paying my wage.

Do I answer never employed or previously employed.

Comment: Who signed your checks? A or B?

Comment: I agree with what Ron said, if you've got a suitable freeform text field use it to elaborate.

Comment: Have you considered simply asking someone at Company A?

Answer (score 2):

Since your paychecks were signed by B, you were never employed by A.  So you'd answer "no" to the question.

If there is space to expand on the answer, you could certainly explain the previous position.  Generally, companies ask the question to determine whether they have existing HR records for the applicant.  If you worked at A for years and left on good terms, the fact that they can pull up your old HR records is a good thing.  If you got fired from A a couple years ago, the old HR records probably disqualify you.  If you weren't employed by A, even if you were employed by B which contracted to do some work for A, A isn't going to have any old HR records to consult.

Comment: Awesome thanks Justin! I'm not sure if this might alter answer. Company A setup our email address with Company A domain name.

Comment: @user46466 - That doesn't matter.  I've had plenty of email addresses for domains I was doing contracting work for.  I've never been employed by any of those companies.